# Execute SSIS packges from C# without integration services installed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I developed SSIS packages on a PC which has integration services installed.
Then i want to develop a C# winforms application execute these packages on client PC. But the client PC has SQL Server installed without integration services.
So i created a C# application and added the packages to it, and added a reference to Microsoft.SQLServe.ManagedDTS then executed the packages, and the result is that some simple packages get executed successfully but complex ones not executed the give an error

> The component metadata for "Script Component, clsid {33D831DE-5DCF-48F0-B431-4D327B9E785D}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.
>   The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "Includes and runs custom script code. For example, apply a business rule that limits the range of valid values in an "income" column or add values in two columns and calculate the average of the sum.;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;10".
>   Script Component failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.

And when i seached online i found most of the solutions is about if integration services is installed right.

My C# code winform code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Package prepartion;
        Package storeLoad;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        Project project = Project.OpenProject(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\SSISLoad.ispac");

        project.Parameters["Con1"].Value = sqlServerTextBox.Text;
        project.Parameters["Con2"].Value = "Dsn=mysqlconn";

        prepartion = project.PackageItems["Preperation.dtsx"].Package;
        storeLoad = project.PackageItems["StoreLoad.dtsx"].Package; 

        pkgResults = prepartion.Execute();

        output.Text = pkgResults.ToString();

        pkgResults = storeLoad.Execute();

        output.Text += "\r\n" + pkgResults.ToString();

        foreach (var x in prepartion.Errors)
        {
            output.Text += "\r\n" + x.Description;
        }

        foreach (var x in storeLoad.Errors)
        {
            output.Text += "\r\n" + x.Description;
        }
    }
```

So is the problem because integration services is not installed on client PC where my application is running or something else ?

And is there a way to get this done without installing integration services on client PC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would that be of any use? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/75f85ed9-7bda-451d-83eb-758a34f0ec83/ssis-custom-component-the-performupgrade-method-failed?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

Not having Integrated services isn't the cause for this error. It seems when your packages are loading something is trying to upgrade them to whatever sql server version your using. I have seen this before when doing upgrades to more recent versions of SSIS or even sometimes SQL Server.